# Bootstrap IMG-RESPONSIVE not working in navbar on Firefox and IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Bootstrap IMG-RESPONSIVE not working in navbar on Firefox and IE. It was working couple of days ago just fine until I did something (unintentionally) and now it only works on google chrome...

here is the link to the page i'm working on:

http://streatham.trustedlocallocksmith.co.uk/

ps. SORRY for not pasting the code in here! wasn't aware of the actual "mission" of the entire site! will not do the same mistake again! PROMISE!

Comment: Please work to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the probelm *in its entirety* with as little code as possible.  Links to external references with no code are of little help to this community.  **See also**: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1366033).

Comment: Easy to edit your question and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

The current .img-responsive class is set to max-width: 100%. You should be able to add a line to override this in your myextras.css, so that you have .img-responsive {width: 100%;}.